# Creating row in both source and association with Sequelize many to many model

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a many to many relationship between a user and a group. A user has many groups and a group has many users.

I have a users table, a groups table and junction table called usersGroups.

My User model:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    username: DataTypes.STRING,
    facebookId: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        User.hasMany(models.Payment);
        User.hasMany(models.Friend, {foreignKey: 'userIdLink1', allowNull: false});
        User.belongsToMany(models.Group, { as: 'Groups', through: 'usersGroups', foreignKey: 'userId' });
      }
    },
    instanceMethods: {
      toJSON: function () {
        var values = Object.assign({}, this.get());

        delete values.password;
        return values;
      }
    }
  });
  return User;
};
```

My group model

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Group = sequelize.define('Group', {
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        Group.belongsToMany(models.User, { as: 'Users', through: 'usersGroups', foreignKey: 'groupId' });
      }
    },
    instanceMethods: {
      toJSON: function () {
        var values = Object.assign({}, this.get());

        delete values.password;
        return values;
      }
    }
  });
  return Group;
};
```

When I try create a new group with associated user with the following 2 methods, it creates a new group but no association

```
const values = {
  userId: 1
}

const options = {
  include: db.Users
}

db.Group
  .create(values, options)
  .then( (group) => {
    res.send(group)
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({err: err})
  })
```

or

```
db.Group
  .create()
  .then( (group) => {

    group.addUser({ userId: 1 }).then(result => {
        res.send(result)
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({err: err})
    })

  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({err: err})
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to assign user to newly created group, you need to use `addUser`, just like you did, but this method accepts first parameter as instance of Model or ID of instance, just like the [`documentation`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/belongs-to-many/#addassociationnewassociation-options-promise) says

> An instance or primary key of instance to associate with this.

So you would have to perform `group.addUser(userId).then(...)` which in your case would be `group.addUser(1).then(...)`.

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear enough in my post but I don't want to create a new user, I want to make an entry in the usersGroups junction table which references the new groupId and an existing userId which I pass in.

Comment: I know, I just thought that I would briefly describe creating model with association, but I also included your case - assigning user to group. I have edited the answer so only this part remains now.